# Adding nodes to Clang's AST

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang

I need to insert new nodes to AST. for instance, adding a namespace to a function:
Turning this -

```
void foo();
```

into this -

```
namespace bar {
    void foo();
}
```

I read [How to clone or create an AST Stmt node of clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451485/how-to-clone-or-create-an-ast-stmt-node-of-clang) but I prefer not using source-to-source compilation

Tnx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer can be found here
http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Adding-nodes-to-Clang-s-AST-td4054800.html

However, the nodes are added to the **compiled** AST - for instance, in case one wants to inject a namespace to the code, he can't use the namespace directly via the code because the lexer don't know about it.

Comment: The link is broken, but even if it worked, this would still be essentially a link-only answer.  The answer could be improved by showing how to accomplish the task with code examples in the answer itself.